# Is it possible to change default format of DateTime when it's casted to a string in code for C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

Is there a way to use the DateTime object in C# and change it's default cast behavior to a string?  When it casts to a string I would prefer it uses a MySQL date/time string format instead of what it uses by default.  I can use a custom object instead, but because it's a struct it makes it more tedious to hide date time as a member and provide functionality on it like a regular date/time object and implement this behavior. I was just curious if it's possible to configure this for DateTime since it's everywhere in a project I am working on.

I think DateTime can be cast using (string)dt and Convert.ChangeType(dt, typeof(string)) so you'd get a default format, that's what I want to control without changing all instances of a DateTime in a project to a new custom object or refactoring all the code.

Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not change datetime class by it self 
 however you can use Extension Method 
to add custom method to datetime class that return you date time in custom format 
for example add method **GetCustomFormat()**

This Article link say to you that how you can add Extention Method to dot net class:
[csharp-extension-method](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-extension-method)

```
DateTime Date = new DateTime();
string Custom =  Date.GetCustomFormat();
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, you can't change the built in type conversion behaviour of `DateTime`, short of replacing it with another type, as you suggest yourself.

Longer answer: To achieve what you are after, you are really looking for a way to convert `DateTime` to `string` in a consistent way that matches your preference. Casting `DateTime` to `string` is actually not allowed in C#, so what you are referring to is probably the conversion of `DateTime` to a string. The preferred way of doing that is the `ToString` method. It has an overload that takes a format string and a `IFormatProvider`; which let's you specify the exact format you want. The `IFormatProvider`is important, because it specifies culture specific formatting and would be taken from the current thread's Cultture if not set. This means your code could behave differently from system to system, so you likely want to specify it to retain control. A good default here is `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Finally, as it sounds like you could need this a lot, to be consistent and reduce typing, you could provide an extension method for `DateTime` to do what you want. Let's say you want just the date (for the sake of the example), then define the extension class:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static string Formatted(this Datetime dt)
    {
        return dt. ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Then use in your code as:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string str = now.Formatted();
```